# SliverAppBar doesn't fully collapse with short list

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm using Flutter's `SliverAppBar` with `SliverList`.
The app bar works fine with long list, that scroll a lot. 
However, if I have medium size list with 8 items the app bar only partially collapses until the list runs out of items. It makes logical sense that the scroll stops because there are no more items but it leaves a really nasty effect on the app bar, which is being left in the middle of its transition in to collapsed toolbar.

Is there a way to force the list to scroll up until the toolbar is fully collapsed?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        label: Text("Start!"),
        icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        elevation: 12,
        onPressed: () {
          Routing.navigate(
            context,
            LoggingPage(
              workout: _workout,
              exercises: workoutExercises,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      body: CustomScrollView( physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            actions: <Widget>[
              MaterialButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("data"),)
            ],
            expandedHeight: 300,
            pinned: true,
            floating: true,
            snap: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text(_workout.name),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              buildSliverListItem,
              childCount: workoutExercises.length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: any update for less complicated solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use NestedScrollView, SliverOverlapAbsorber and SliverOverlapInjector based on Code With Andrea's example here

https://github.com/bizz84/slivers_demo_flutter/blob/master/lib/pages/nested_scroll_view_page.dart.

We use a NestedScrollView. First, we embed the SliverAppbar within the headerSliverBuilder with a SliverOverlapAbsorber above the SliverAppBar.

Next, we embed the CustomScrollView within a builder inside the body of the NestedScrollView. We add a SliverOverlapInjector at the top of the body.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled){
          return <Widget>[
            SliverOverlapAbsorber(
              handle:
              NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
              sliver: SliverAppBar(

                pinned: true,
                //floating: true,
                stretch: true,
                expandedHeight: 300.0,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: const Text('Weather Report'),
                  background: Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/logo1.jpg',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Builder(
              builder:(BuildContext context) {
                return CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverOverlapInjector(
                      // This is the flip side of the SliverOverlapAbsorber above.
                      handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                          context),
                    ),
                    SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                          (BuildContext context, int i){
                            return ListTile(
                              leading: Icon(Icons.wb_sunny),
                              title: i%2 != 1 ? Text('Sunday ${i+1}') : Text('Monday ${i+1}'),
                              subtitle: Text('sunny, h: 80, l: 65'),
                            );
                          },
                        childCount: 5
                      ),
                    ),

                  ],
                );
              }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use widget with custom RenderSliver. It must be added to the end of a slivers list.

```
class CustomRenderSliver extends RenderSliver {
  final double _minHeaderHeight;
  final double _maxHeaderHeight;

  CustomRenderSliver(this._minHeaderHeight, this._maxHeaderHeight);

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    double maxHeight = this.constraints.viewportMainAxisExtent -
        (this.constraints.precedingScrollExtent - _maxHeaderHeight) /*height of regular list elements*/ -
        _minHeaderHeight;

    if (maxHeight < 0.0) maxHeight = 0.0;

    this.geometry = SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: maxHeight);
  }
}
```

[list with custom sliver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvHzF.gif)

Complete code

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() {
  final minHeaderHeight = 90.0;
  final maxHeaderHeight = 180.0;

  List<Widget> slivers = List.generate(4, (index) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 100,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  });

  // header
  slivers.insert(
      0, SliverPersistentHeader(
    pinned: true,
    delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
        minHeight: minHeaderHeight,
        maxHeight: maxHeaderHeight
    ),
  ));

  // custom sliver
  slivers.add(CustomRenderSliverWidget(minHeaderHeight, maxHeaderHeight));

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: slivers,
    ),
  ));
}

class CustomRenderSliverWidget extends LeafRenderObjectWidget {
  final double _minHeaderHeight;
  final double _maxHeaderHeight;

  CustomRenderSliverWidget(this._minHeaderHeight, this._maxHeaderHeight);

  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomRenderSliver(_minHeaderHeight, _maxHeaderHeight);
  }
}

class CustomRenderSliver extends RenderSliver {
  final double _minHeaderHeight;
  final double _maxHeaderHeight;

  CustomRenderSliver(this._minHeaderHeight, this._maxHeaderHeight);

  @override
  void performLayout() {
    double maxHeight = this.constraints.viewportMainAxisExtent -
        (this.constraints.precedingScrollExtent - _maxHeaderHeight) /*height of regular list elements*/ -
        _minHeaderHeight;

    if (maxHeight < 0.0) maxHeight = 0.0;

    this.geometry = SliverGeometry(scrollExtent: maxHeight);
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate({
    @required this.minHeight,
    @required this.maxHeight,
  });

  final double minHeight;
  final double maxHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => minHeight;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => max(maxHeight, minHeight);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset,
      bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(color: Colors.red,);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return maxHeight != oldDelegate.maxHeight ||
        minHeight != oldDelegate.minHeight;
  }
}
```